# Wamp - Service has not been started

Tags: apache, wamp

I am at a loss here.  I installed wamp2.5.

When I try to put it online I get a message as follows.

[image]

I tried changing the port in the apache.conf file to 8080, but I still get the same message.
Skype is not using port 80.

Doing the following also did not work
    * Press (Windows+R)
    * enter "services.msc" and click "OK"
    * locate service with name 'wampapache'

Tried starting it from here and tried setting it to automatic start, but i get this

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I got to the bottom of this.

After investigating the `windows system event log` 
reachable like this.
*Start button***->***Control Panel***->***System and Security***->***Administrative Tools***->***Event Viewer*

Wamp is installed on my `H:\` drive

so in my `httpd-autoindex.conf` file i had the following by default as per instalation

> ```
> Alias /icons/ "c:/Apache24/icons"
>
> <Directory "c:/Apache24/icons">
>     Options Indexes MultiViews
>     AllowOverride None
>     Require all granted
> </Directory>
> ```

When I changed it to the following everything just worked.

> ```
> Alias /icons/ "icons/"
>
> <Directory "icons">
>     Options Indexes MultiViews
>     AllowOverride None
>     Order allow,deny
>     Allow from all 
> </Directory>
> ```

Comment: Well done. As a rule of thumb, WAMPServer install only tailors the basic conf file for where you install it i.e. `C:/D:/` etc. If you uncomment any of the `#Include` files they must be sanity checked as they are left as per a default Apache install.